# Difference between addChildEventListener, addValueEventListener, and addOnCompleteListener when using orderByChild()?

Tags: java, android, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to sort and display data from Firebase using orderByChild() and used:

```
ref.child("dinosaurs").orderByChild("height").get().addOnCompleteListener(...);
```

I kept on wondering why it's not sorting until I realized that `childEventListener` was used in the documentation. It should've been:

```
ref.child("dinosaurs").orderByChild("height").addChildEventListener(...);
```

What is the difference between the two and `addValueEventListener` when it comes to using `orderByChild` or any sorting method? Does `get()` not follow `orderByChild()`?

Comment: Answer below . In future questions please ensure you have the minimal **complete** reproduction of the problem, as here the problem comes from how you handle the results - not how you query them.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. I overlooked that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the methods you describe return the child nodes in the order your query requests.

Most likely you're calling `getValue()` on the complete `DataSnapshot` you get though. Doing so converts the results to a `Map` and (by definition) the order of the keys in a map is undefined.

When you're using `addChildEventListener`, your `onChildAdded` gets called for each individual child snapshot in order already, so you have no way to make this mistake.

To process the resulting child nodes in the order you requested them in `onDataChange` and when using `get()`, you need to loop over `getChildren()` of the `DataSnapshot` you get back, as shown in the documentation on [listening for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) on a list of children.

So something like:

```
ref.child("dinosaurs").orderByChild("height").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
        }
        else {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("FIREBASE", childSnapshot.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. I also used the same loop as in your example and never used getValue. It turns out I was updating data using string values instead of integer which affects sorting. The other problem is that, after updating data in one activity and accessing that data from another activity, the ones that get displayed is the old data which is weird 'coz I can see my database getting updated but get() seems to fetch cached data. And that's probably better addressed in a new question.

Comment: Nvm. I wasn't syncing my data that's why old data gets displayed. Thanks a lot.